# NSString \u0026 to &

Tags: ios, objective-c

I download html file with my app and noticed for a lot of :

```
\u0026
```

I search the net and noticed that in equal to : `&`

So i try to replace it to & with :

```
newStr = [newStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/u0026" withString:@"&"];
```

But all the `\u0026` are in the string and won't replace.
Any idea why it happen?

Comment: Because you used `/` instead of `\\\`?

Comment: not the greatest question title

Comment: @MaxMacLeod -- Dunno -- I think with the `[duplicate]` it's quite artistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need to be using here is CFStringTransform()
That Core Foundation  function is going to come in real hand for anybody trying to convert to and from escaped forms.

Comment: That's interesting.  What transform name would be used?  Any-Hex/Java reversed?

Comment: Hex-Any by itself will do. Works like a charm.

Comment: It is a wrapper around the ICU libraries, and provides a lot of convenience and a fair amount of functionality from ICU is in Cocoa or under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the substring `\u0026` then you need:

```
newStr = [newStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u0026" withString:@"&"];
```

Note there needs to be two backslashes.